# How to create a well designed REST API in Perl with Mason?

Tags: perl, rest, mason

The website I'm working on is written in Perl and Mason, hosted by Apache2 (mod_perl).
I'm looking for a well designed, easy-to-use REST API "framework" or just something well established approach to create one.
Mojolicious is not an option as I'm sending requests back to Apache2 on port 80.
I could barely find anything related to this on Google and what I found looks garbage.
I'm asking those of you who have designed a REST API in Perl and Mason to show a good example.

So, what I found is to check `$r->method()` to see what REST method is used and execute code accordingly. Would be nice if this could somehow written like this:

```
POST => sub {
   ...
}
GET => sub { 
   ...
}
DELETE => sub {
   ...
}
```

That was just an idea.

Comment: "Mojolicious is not an option as I'm sending requests back to Apache2 on port 80" — I don't understand how that follows.

Comment: Mason is a template language. It is not at all well suited to REST.

Comment: Yeah, that wasn't clear enough. I think Mojolicious cannot be integrated into an Apache hosted website. But I may be wrong about it, and thus I don't want to open two ports: one for apache, one for mojo.
Mojo would be great though. I very much like it.

Comment: https://github.com/kraih/mojo/wiki/Apache-deployment

Comment: Thanks @Quentin. That looks promising. If you create a nice answer I'll accept it as a solution.

Comment: I can't really write a nice answer for this. I've basically given a product recommendation and pointed out that your question was based on a false premise.

Comment: Everything that speaks PSGI can be integrated into an Apache webserver. If it's hosted and you can only do CGI it might be slow, but it will work.

Answer (score 3):

Mason is aimed at building HTML pages. It is very much the wrong tool to use to build an API - which is (presumably) going to be returning JSON rather than HTML.

To build an API, you will be creating data structures and then (hopefully) using one of CPAN's JSON libraries to convert those data structures to JSON. There's really no place for Mason in that workflow.

And I don't think you should be constrained to using the same technology for your web site and your API. If the web site is at http://www.example.com/ then you can put your API at http://api.example.com/ and run it on a completely different technology (even a different web server).

Without knowing a lot more about your project, it's hard to give much concrete advice. But if you have DBIx::Class classes for your data, it's work having a look at [WebAPI::DBIC](https://metacpan.org/release/WebAPI-DBIC) - that would be far easier than writing your own code using a framework.